# I want to get the home root path

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have created a file for ajax in `theme/mytheme/ajax-form.php` and there was an error while using this code:

```
$db_result = $wpdb->get_results( 'select * from batch_number' );
```

> **Error:** `get_result` is not a function

Then I've included `wp-config.php` and `wp-load.php` at the top, so the issue was fixed and I got the result, but now the issue is: I'm hard coding the path of `wp-config.php` file. Instead, can we take the root path of my project?

I've tried many things, but no luck. I've tried this:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wptheme/wp-load.php' );
```

`wptheme` is my project's root folder and I don't want to hardcode it like that.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using admin-ajax or the REST API? Those are the preferred way to do AJAX on WordPress.

Comment: basically i am learning wordpress coding , i dont know much about wordpress but somehow i have tried and achieved ajax but only this issue is left

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE! It's OK that you are learning, testing & breaking some things yourself. There is nothing wrong in that. However, it's better if you learn from the correct source, otherwise you may not even know that you are doing it wrong, until it's too late. Try to learn from the documents found [HERE](https://developer.wordpress.org).

Comment: @Fayaz ye i will definitely look the correct way , but i am willing to learn this thing it is done but i just dont want to hard code the path of wp-config file so i want to know how can we call this

Comment: There is no correct answer. Because in WordPress it's possible to change Theme directory. However, if theme directory isn't changed, then you can use relative path, like: `require_once(  '../../../wp-load.php' );`. This will work since by default the theme files are in `wp-content/themes/theme-name/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your ajax doing approach is wrong when WordPress offer us great way to do this. Read this one [why you should't use your current approach](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) and then read https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins how you can do ajax with `wp_ajax` hook. It's really simple and easy. using this hook you don't need to call external file neither need to load wp-load.php

Anyway to include wp-load.php file just use `ABSPATH` like this

```
$rootPath = str_replace(ABSPATH,"",getcwd());
```

Then include

```
include( $rootPath . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Moral, For using ajax in WordPress used WordPress `wp_ajax` hook instead any others.

Comment: yes you are right i will try to use built in features but right now i am learning so i can practice different things right ?

Comment: i have tried your way of getting path but it is not working first erro ABSPATH is not defined ... second if i define ABSPATH as it is defined in wp-config.php then it is getting the path of the theme folder . not the root directory

Comment: Yeah sure, I did this type of practice before learning about WordPress feature :P . So my opinion it's not bad thing to do but just let you know that WordPress offer great feature to do this and off-course use WordPress feature when you did in real project.

Comment: ABSPATH is a PHP constant defined by WordPress at the bottom of wp-config.php:

Comment: :) yes i know i have seen it on all other files wp-config file is auto load but if i create file in themes directory forexample like this ajax-form.php then in this file we have to call wp-config file ... and ABSPATH is not callable here